# does cex scale the radius, diameter, or area when applied to circular points in base R plots

Tags: r, scatter-plot

The graphical parameter `cex` determines the size of various things in base R plots, from labels to point sizes. `cex = 1` is the default size, `cex = .5` is 50% smaller, `cex = 1.5` is 50% larger. My question is what exactly cex uses to scale circular point sizes. For example, when `cex = 1.5` does that mean the area, radius, or diameter of the point is 50% bigger than default?

Example of cex changing circular point size:

```
plot(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, type = "n")
points(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, pch = 21, cex = 1)
points(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, pch = 21, cex = 2)
```

Comment: Scaling the radius is the same as scaling the diameter.

Comment: [How does the cex parameter scale circles?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/271234.html), answered by Ripley: "[`cex`] is linear magnification: that is 
all linear dimensions (including height and width) are proportional to 
`cex`)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It scales the radius (or, equivalently, the diameter).

```
plot(x = -1:1, y = -1:1, type = "n")
points(0, 0, cex = 20)
points(0, 0, cex = 40)
abline(v=0)
abline(v=0.5)
abline(v=1)
```

[image]